# Use HTML5 <video> tag with database

Tags: html, video-streaming

Is it possible to use HTML5  tag to stream video from PostgreSQL database using Java?

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I suppose that this solution can be implemented if I move the file in some /tmp directory and read the content. But I would like to know can I read the stream directly from DB?
If the use selects random video time how I can jump to this timeframe?

Answer (score 0):

You should store location of your video file in the database.

Then you retrieve location of video using php.

It will be streaming directly from server.

Comment: Ok, but can you propose some solution to the above question?

Comment: i dont know about PostgreSQL but can give solution with Mysql